# Extending heavy client by a mobile application

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

I have a normal desktop application written in C#. Now I want an extra mobile application that uses the same information / data from the desktop application.

My question is how can I make a connection between my desktop application and my mobile application?

Atm I got two solution in mind:
-Make a webservice to provide data for the mobile application
-Use a database where the application can write stuff and the mobile application can read stuff from here

What do you guys think?

Comment: You have a server (listener) with lots of clients that connect.  You want to relay messages from one client to second client using the server.  Am I correct?

Comment: I have noticed u have unaccepted my answer,  did I say something worng or u got stuck?

Comment: I got stuck , I need more technical details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing todo is to make like a REST service for it. This REST services communicates with your database to get the needed data from your database to your mobile application.

In your mobile application you make calls to this service using httpclient to get the data on your phone. You could chose to save this data locally in an SQLite database ( so people can use the app also offline ).

Hope this helps